# Anime that takes place on a floating island powered by a sleeping girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

So this anime takes place on a floating island powered by a sleeping girl. The main character went there, I think, and his grandma/mom is sick. There the kids get special powers and they learn how to use them, and they use the powers to protect the city. I think the boy got a job as a bodyguard of an actress and he falls in love with her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Do you recall the names of any characters or places?

Comment: No i do not, i think i saw it early 2021/late 2020, i remember the animation was pretty good probaubly something after 200

Comment: There's a [floating island](https://anidb.net/anime/?atags.include=floating%20island&h=1&noalias=1&orderby.airdate=0.2&orderby.name=1.1) tag on anidb that doesn't have very many results, and includes images. Might be a good place to start.

Comment: I remember that the mc has a gf but is secretly in a relationship with a singer tha the works for as a body guard

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't be ***[Castle in the Sky](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092067/)***? An old film that is kicking about on [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/gb/title/60027393?tctx=4%2C4%2C2667f6b3-32c2-44db-a752-998239c6ac49-276922192%2CNES_0BC25FC9B6F178DE948286DCA8DA83-B9F225DDE3A711-142AA98931_p_1671615700281%2CNES_0BC25FC9B6F178DE948286DCA8DA83_p_1671615695021%2C%2C%2C%2C&trackId=14170287).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky):

> *Castle in the Sky* (Japanese: 天空の城ラピュタ, Hepburn: *Tenkuu no Shiro Laputa*), titled *Laputa: Castle in the Sky* for release in the United Kingdom, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand, is a 1986 Japanese animated fantasy adventure film written and directed by Hayao Miyazaki. The first film produced by Studio Ghibli, it was produced for Tokuma Shoten. Set in a fictional late 19th century, it follows the adventures of a boy and girl who are trying to keep a powerful crystal from the army, a group of secret agents, and a family of pirates, while searching for a legendary floating castle. The film was distributed by Toei Company.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how this anime matches the one described in the question. For example, was the island powered by a sleeping girl? Was the main character's grandmother/mother sick? Etc.

Comment: Seriously doubt it. The premise and plotline of Laputa is nothing like the description in the question about the only thing they have in common is an "island" floating in the sky.